# How can I temporarily extend storage for a system update?

Tags: ubuntu, updates, storage

Following situation: I have a 16GB micro SSD plus a 128GB SSD in my notebook, with Ubuntu 14 installed on the 16GB one. Works perfectly since my home dir is on the larger storage SSD and I have around 2 GB free memory on the small one. But when i want to update to version 16, Ubuntu complains about not enough space left. I already tried uninstalling as much as possible but I can't get it much smaller than 14GB.

Now my question is: How can I update without having to reset up the system completely? Alternatively, is there a way to figure what else I can uninstall? I already used synaptics to get rid of about any package I didn't need (I actually wonder why Ubuntu takes up that much space).

Thanks in advance!

Edit: In case someone else has this problem: Remove your old kernels, they need loads of storage! Check your current kernel version with `uname -r` and then list your old kernels with `dpkg -l | grep linux-image`. You can remove your old ones with this command, changing the version numbers accordingly (I actually had a HUGE amount of kernels): `sudo apt-get purge linux-image-3.13.0-{32,43,46,48,49,61,62,63,65,66,67,68,71,74,76,77,79,83,85,86,87,88,91,92}-generic`

Answer (score 0):

Do not run a full dist-upgrade, upgrade a minimal group of packages once. For example: `libc6` and dependencies first, then `browser`, then `libreoffice`, then `gimp`, then `ffmpeg`, and so on... And don't forget to `apt-get clean` between each update.

Comment: Can you provide an example command? I usually update && upgrade && dist-upgrade everything so `apt-get dist-upgrade libc6` tells me libc6 is up to date.

Comment: `apt-get install libc6`

Comment: Well I already did that with most packets, they are mostly up to date. Which ones are really big?

Comment: `apt-get dist-upgrade` shows you the updateable packages. Select some names then copy-paste after `apt-get install` ....